# Pick line with the highest value of birth in every shop-country section

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

have been trying for several hours to resolve the problem but i cant sos 
here is the tables im working with on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mfiMUcry)

```
var result = E
                .Join(A, a => a.ID, aa => aa.ID,
                    (EE, AA) => new {AA.ID, AA.Birth, AA.Street, EE.Code, EE.Shop})
                .Join(D, d => d.Code, dd => dd.Code,
                    (AE, DD) => new {AE.ID, AE.Birth, AE.Street, AE.Shop, DD.Code, DD.Price})
                .Join(B, b => b.Code, bb => bb.Code,
                    (AED, BB) => new {AED.ID, AED.Birth, AED.Shop, AED.Price, BB.Country})
                .GroupBy(g => new
                {
                    g.ID, g.Birth, g.Shop, g.Country
                })
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    s.Key.ID, s.Key.Birth, 
                    ShopCont = s.Key.Shop + "-" + s.Key.Country, 
                    Total = s.Sum(ss => ss.Price)
                });
```

and this is what result looks like

```
{ ID = 1, Birth = 1992, ShopCont = Gucci-Nigeria, Total = 64 }
{ ID = 2, Birth = 2001, ShopCont = Gucci-Russia, Total = 41 }
{ ID = 3, Birth = 1998, ShopCont = Gucci-Russia, Total = 123 } // this should be removed
{ ID = 3, Birth = 1998, ShopCont = Dior-Russia, Total = 32 } 
{ ID = 4, Birth = 2003, ShopCont = Dior-USA, Total = 23 }
{ ID = 1, Birth = 1992, ShopCont = Adidas-USA, Total = 1290 }
{ ID = 1, Birth = 1992, ShopCont = Adidas-Germany, Total = 321 }
{ ID = 5, Birth = 2005, ShopCont = Dixi-Germany, Total = 4 }
{ ID = 5, Birth = 2005, ShopCont = Dixi-France, Total = 1890 }
{ ID = 4, Birth = 2003, ShopCont = Dixi-France, Total = 1695 } // this should be removed
```

and i want to see this

```
{ ID = 1, Birth = 1992, ShopCont = Gucci-Nigeria, Total = 64 }
{ ID = 2, Birth = 2001, ShopCont = Gucci-Russia, Total = 41 }
{ ID = 3, Birth = 1998, ShopCont = Dior-Russia, Total = 32 }
{ ID = 4, Birth = 2003, ShopCont = Dior-USA, Total = 23 }
{ ID = 1, Birth = 1992, ShopCont = Adidas-USA, Total = 1290 }
{ ID = 1, Birth = 1992, ShopCont = Adidas-Germany, Total = 321 }
{ ID = 5, Birth = 2005, ShopCont = Dixi-Germany, Total = 4 }
{ ID = 5, Birth = 2005, ShopCont = Dixi-France, Total = 1890 }
```

Comment: Why do you think those lines should be removed?  They are not duplicates.  They are different years.

Comment: yes you're right but the purpose is to pick line with the highest value of birth in every shop-country section. it is the exercise from the book

Comment: Do a OrderByDescending(x => x.Total) then a GroupBy(x => x.ShopCont) and finally select first from each group .Select(x => x.First())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding `GroupBy` + `Select` (`SelectMany`) at the very end of the query:

```
var result = E
   ...
  .Select(s => new {
     s.Key.ID, 
     s.Key.Birth, 
     ShopCont = s.Key.Shop + "-" + s.Key.Country, 
     Total    = s.Sum(ss => ss.Price)
   })
  .GroupBy(item => item.ShopCont) // we group by shop
  .Select(g => g                  // in each shop
     .OrderByDescending(item => item.Birth) // we take the latest
     .First());                             // item only
```

here we *group* by `Birth`, take the only latest one.

**Edit:** If we can have *duplicate* `Birth` we can *group* by them (I'd rather implement my own extensions method, but when solving problems from a book it's usually not allowed):

```
  ... 
  .Select(s => new {
          s.Key.ID,
          s.Key.Birth, // Let's declare it explicitly
          ShopCont = s.Key.Shop + "-" + s.Key.Country,
          Total = s.Sum(ss => ss.Price)
        })
  .GroupBy(item => item.ShopCont) // we group by shop
  .SelectMany(outer => outer
    .GroupBy(item => item.Birth)
    .OrderByDescending(inner => inner.Key)
    .First());
```

Now we *group* by `Birth` (we want a group, since it can be more than just one single record to return); with `OrderByDescending` followed by `First` take the right group which we finally flatten with a help of `SelectMany`

Comment: [CS0411] The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @invis: Sorry, you want just one item (the latest one) from the entire group; since we have just one item, there's nothing to flatten and no `SelectMany` required (but `Select`)

Comment: but what if there are not only one the highest value, then we need to take all the of them. what should i do here

Comment: So, if we have *two or more* recordes with the same `ShopCont` and `Birth` we have to keep them *all*?